Do while loop to collect rates based on user input
I'd really appreciate the help here... I have an array of rates, e.g.
[
  [
    'rate_id' => 1,
    'after' => 0,
    'units' => 0,
    'rate' => 0
  ],
  [
    'rate_id' => 2,
    'after' => 8,
    'units' => 0,
    'rate' => 12
  ],
  [
    'rate_id' => 3,
    'after' => 12,
    'units' => 0,
    'rate' => 15
  ]
]
]

And I need to take an inputted total time e.g. say 15.5 hours for 1 day and loop through the rates and split the 15 hours into the respective array key, so the first array item should contain  the first 8 hours, then 4 in the second one, then 3.5 in the last.
The above array is the data for a rate sheet, so each "after" is the when the overtime rate kicks in.
Please any help I would really appreciate, as I'm struggling to get this working accurately with decimal places.
So far I have tried doing a php do/while loop, here's my code from my laravel app so far.
$totalTime = $item->units;

                $rates = $item->timesheet->rates()
                    ->orderBy('after', 'desc')
                    ->get()
                    ->keyBy('after')
                    ->map(function($item) {
                        return [
                            'units' => 0,
                            'rate_id' => $item['id']
                        ];
                    })->toArray();

                do {
                    foreach ($rates as $after => $rate) {
                        if ($totalTime >= $after) {
                            $rates[$after]['units'] = $rates[$after]['units'] + 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    $totalTime -= 1;
                } while ($totalTime >= 1);

                $rates = collect($rates)->filter(function ($item, $key) {
                    return $item['units'] > 0;
                });

This works I think so far, but it doesn't work if the $totalTime is a decimal place, rounds it up/down to the nearest decimal because we are only decrementing by 1, instead of by 0.1, but if I decrement it by 0.1 it also doesn't work properly as when we get below 0 it starts doing 0.9, 0.8, 0.7 etc.

Your split logic is unclear

It is often times more beneficial to choose a smaller unit and only convert for user convenience / readability at the end. So changing to minutes would avoid working in decimal places and would keep the same logic. To be fair your code will have to execute 60 times more often if you have to keep the loop that way.

So this is incremental thing. We will for from the start, filling the hours while reducing amount from $totalTime
$arr = [
    [
        'rate_id' => 1,
        'after' => 0,
        'units' => 0,
        'rate' => 0
    ],
    [
        'rate_id' => 2,
        'after' => 8,
        'units' => 0,
        'rate' => 12
    ],
    [
        'rate_id' => 3,
        'after' => 12,
        'units' => 0,
        'rate' => 15
    ]
];

$totalTime = 15.5;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr) - 1; $i++) {
    $shift = $arr[$i + 1]['after'] - $arr[$i]['after'];
    $worked = min($totalTime, $shift);
    $arr[$i]['units'] = $worked;
    $totalTime -= $worked;
}
if (count($arr)) {
    $arr[count($arr) - 1]['units'] = $totalTime;
}

print_r($arr);

// output:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rate_id] => 1
            [after] => 0
            [units] => 8
            [rate] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rate_id] => 2
            [after] => 8
            [units] => 4
            [rate] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [rate_id] => 3
            [after] => 12
            [units] => 3.5
            [rate] => 15
        )

)



Thanks! This looks right! I did something very similar in the end, and managed to figure it out. but I thought I'd mark it as correct as it looks pretty much the same as what I've done
